# Google Maps v3 - marker and overlay map type load event?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to detect when all markers and overlay map types are loaded to the map. I was searching for proper events, but I couldn't find any.

Is there an event triggered when marker is fully loaded?

And similarly, is there an event triggered when overlay map type is loaded? 
I know that there's actually `tilesloaded` event for `google.maps.Map`, but it seems to work only for the base map types.

Answer (score 1):

I use `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map,'idle',callback)` to determine when everything is loaded.